# Deploying to Heroku(table does not exist error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a sample pre-sign up page where people can signup their email before the application launches. When I type in:

```
heroku open
```

I get the following error on my browser

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

After checking my logs, I found this weird error:

```
[36m2014-04-28T08:22:01.921791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:
 relation "premails" does not exist
```

what does that mean? I have the following migration:

```
class CreatePremails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :premails do |t|

        t.text :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and model:

```
class Premail < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

What do I need to do to make it deploy on Heroku? I am not sure if that is the problem or if perhaps I need to change my database.yml file. currently I have this in there:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Since Heroku only works on pg maybe I need to make a change there?

Some additional information, here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'pg'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I am on Windows8 64

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: That did it! Damn so simple!

Comment: Nice! I wrote an answer to describe where the issue probably stood as well

Comment: btw how do you develop on Windows 8!??

Comment: I've been learning for just a few months. I only had a Windows so had too.. Ran into problems at first but then you start learning Windows little intricacies. I'll probably run Linux at some point once I get more advanced.

Comment: So something is happening that I don't understand. When using heroku open to view my page it looks good but when trying to view it using rails s (localhost) it wont work. I'm getting this error: ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified
database configuration does not specify adapter

Comment: What does your database.yml file look like? Are you running any db on your local host?

Comment: I've moved it into a questions of its own here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336755/activerecordadapternotspecified-database-configuration-does-not-specify-adapte

Comment: Let me know if you know how to fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several issues:

> 1. You've not set a "real" production database
> 2. You've not used `rake db:migrate` in production

Firstly, you need to [create a production db to run on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql). Heroku does not host any db for you - it only runs on the Amazon EC2 stack; meaning you have to either prodivde your own DB server, or use one of Heroku's `postgres` instances

After you have a production database, you'll just need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` from your command-line to get all your tables populated on the db server, which should resolve the error