# ActiveRecord's configuration error - ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Why doesn't the program run?

list.rb

```
require 'active_record'
require 'yaml'

ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = YAML.load_file('./database.yml')
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('development')

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
end

student = Student.find('123')
puts student.id
puts student.name
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_name
```

list.db

sqlite> select * from students;

```
123|foo|foo@email.com
```

error

```
../activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:170:in `spec': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified database configuration does not specify adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336755/activerecordadapternotspecified-database-configuration-does-not-specify-adapte)

Comment: I've changed to above database.yml but the error happened again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a string to identify the database config I wanted to use instead of a symbol (which Rails 5 seems to require)

Try this:

`ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)`