# heroku gives error ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'production' database is not configured. Available: ["development", "test"]

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-cli

My database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: organic_tomatoes_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: organic_tomatoes_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
```

I deploy my site on heroku.
When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`
it gives an error

```
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'production' database is not configured. Available: ["development", "test"]
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified database configuration does not specify adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336755/activerecordadapternotspecified-database-configuration-does-not-specify-adapte)

Comment: @KickButtowski i tried that not solution works

Answer (score 1):

As per the description shared you only have development and test envirinment specified , you need to add production environment settings as well

But apart from.that you need to add ClearDB as an add-on to use mysql db.

Click Reveal Config Vars and copy the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL value.

mysql://xxxxx@xxxx.cleardb.net/xxxxx?reconnect=true.

Everything after the @ symbol until the / is the DB_HOST

Everything after / until ? is DB_DATABASE

The string after the // until : is the DB_USERNAME

The string between : and @ is the DB_PASSWORD

```
   development:
     adapter: mysql2
     encoding: utf8
     reconnect: false
     database: organic_tomatoes_development
     pool: 5
     username: root
     password: password

   test:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    reconnect: false
    database: organic_tomatoes_test
    pool: 5
    username: root
    password: password

   production:
     adapter: mysql2
     encoding: utf8
     username: xxxx
     password: xxxx
    database: ENV["CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"]
    pool: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a production entry in your database.yml

```
production::
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: organic_tomatoes_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
```

Answer (score 0):

```
production:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    reconnect: false
    database: organic_tomatoes_production
    pool: 5
```

Can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue this morning and the solution is to set `RAILS_ENV` variable before running the command'

```
RAILS_ENV=development heroku local
```